# $datediff in mongodb subtract hours of sundays between two dates

Tags: mongodb

```
[
  {
    startDate: ISODate("2023-08-05T16:02:50.000Z"),
    endDate: ISODate("2023-08-06T02:06:18.000Z")
  },
  {
    startDate: ISODate("2023-12-10T10:24:51.303Z"),
    endDate: ISODate("2024-01-30T10:24:51.303Z")
  }
]



expected Output,
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "diffWeeks": NumberLong(0),
    "exceptSundays": 10,
    "waitTime": NumberLong(10)
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "diffWeeks": NumberLong(7),
    "exceptSundays": 1056,
    "waitTime": NumberLong(1224)
  }
]
```

For the first document in the example there is no sunday in between startDate and endDate but it considers a sunday in between in below tried example. Can anybody explain how this is working.

tried this ,
https://mongoplayground.net/p/SLI0XTOQtlI

Comment: Adding code in mongoplayground is nice since it lets everyone run it, but please also add the code to the question, so it will be available to future StackOverflow visitors even after it is no longer available on mongoplayground.net